# How to return false instead of Assertion Error?

Tags: python, function, error-handling, assertion

I have a boolean function where I am using the assert command in python. This means if all the assertions are correct the function returns True however, when an assertion is not satisfied I get an error. I want it to just return false instead.

However when I test it is throws a assertion error(quiet rightly so) , I am wondering is there a way to take the error and return false instead?

Right now I am using if not statements to return false if the assertion is invalid but because I have a lot of assertion my code is getting a bit long.

Comment: If you don't want it to raise an error, why *are* you using assert?

Comment: so all the conditions are satisfied before returning true.

Comment: Write an`assert`-like _function_ that does what you want.

Comment: Maybe you should read about what you're using, and have a rethink: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement

Answer (score 3):

You can catch the exception with an try: except block

```
try:
    assert condition1 # or whatever you want to check
    assert condition2 # ...
except AssertionError:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

But I don't the sense to use an assert for an boolean condition only to encapsulate it in a try except block to return true or false. You could get the same behaviour with a simple and statement:

```
result = condition1 and condition2 # ....
```

or you wrap all your conditions in a high level function to increase code readability:

```
def high_level_condition():
    return condition1 and condition2
```

Assert seems not to be the right language feature for this kind of task.
I only would use assert to check invariants to check that the program behaves as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be using assert here, just use a conditional statement.

```
if not (whatever your assert was):
    return false
```

Comment: i fixed it, my bad